# How to change the default wrapper (ie 'h2') of a form title in Zend Form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

Iam using zend_Form for creating forms in my project

The form titles are wrapped by 'h2' tag in default.

How can i change it to 'h3' tag,so that particular form title will wrapped by 'h3' tag.

Following  is my code

```
class Core_Form_Contact extends Zend_Form
{
  public function init()
  {
    $this->setTitle('Contact Us');
  }
}
```

Any one have idea?

Comment: could we see the setTitle() method and see how you're actually creating the element?

Comment: What is your ZF version used? I am a bit confused. I have never seen this method before.